# setting all nodes of a tree in italics with forest

Tags: forest

I want to define a style for setting type hierarchies with `forest` and the types should come out in italics. I read the manual, but ... I found some examples that use the content of a node and do something with it (appending indices and so on). I tried several things, for instance the one in the code below (`content=\textit{#1}`), but they did not work. So how is this done right?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{typehierarchy/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child
           anchor=north,align=center,base=top,content=\textit{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
typehierarchy
[lexeme
  [active ]
  [passive] ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `font=\itshape` or `node font=\itshape` options, both produce the desired result with your MWE.

[image]

Section **17.4.2 Text Parameters: Font** in `TiKZ` documentation explains the difference between these options but I'm not sure about which one should be used within `forest`. 
Next code uses `font`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{typehierarchy/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child
           anchor=north,align=center,base=top,font=\itshape}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
typehierarchy
[lexeme
  [active ]
  [passive] ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `Forest` doesn't know or care about the difference between  `node font` and `font`: it simply passes their values on to `tikz`.  Note that even when using `node font` (which was added to `tikz` in v3, for the reason of adjusting the node size and margins based on the selected font, I presume), `forest` still calculates the dimensions for separating the nodes based on the `em` and `ex` of the outer (surrounding text) font when (as in the default settings) `s sep` and similar dimensions are given using font-dependent units.